# AngularJS servlet response call method

Tags: angularjs, servlets, response

I have some code that posts to a servlet and gets a response, the problem is that I want the response to open an alert box and tell the user if the post was Success or Fail. I can make the response (which is just text) whatever... success(); or some HTML

Okay, seemed to have fixed it...

Java Servlet

```
printWriter.println("200");
```

HTML

```
<script> function success() {alert('SUCCESS');}</script>
<script> function fail() {alert('FAIL');}</script>
```

AngularJS

```
.then(function(response)
        {
            if (response.data == 200) 
            {
                success();
            } 
            else 
            {
                fail();
            }
        })
```

Comment: Can you show you `post` call code? code you have posted look fine to me.. are you getting any errors?

Comment: the post, posts data to a database then response returns a String which can be whatever I like

Comment: Does your response returns just a string? Because you have used `response.data` which is an object

Comment: the java servlet - `response.setContentType("text/html");` so its just a String as far as I can tell

Comment: I believe you should use `response.setContentType("text/plain");` if you just want to return a `string` back. If you want to return a `json` the use `response.setContentType("application/json");`

Comment: a number without quotes seems to work

Answer (score 0):

You can use it like :

```
.then(function(response) {
    $scope.status = response.status;
    $scope.data = response.data;
}, function(response) {
    $scope.data = response.data || 'Request failed';
    $scope.status = response.status;
})
```

Comment: so the response.status should be a code, maybe 200. I'm trying to get this working